# The rate of $L_1$ convergence for the sample average

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I get stuck on proving the following statement: $$\mathbb{E}(|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i - \mu|) = O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}})\text{ as } N\rightarrow\infty$$
$X_i$'s are i.i.d random variables with finite variance and $\mu$ is its expectation.

Could anyone share some idea about the proof? Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Is this true, how do you prove this, how is it used in some specific case? As it stands, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear. I am asking how to prove this statement.

Comment: Then edit your question. As it stands, there is no way to see that (except through your comment, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_n = \displaystyle \sqrt n\left( \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i-\mu\right)$.
By the central limit theorem $Y_n$ converges in distribution to some $Y\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$, so by the continuous mapping theorem, $|Y_n|$ converges in distribution to $|Y|$.

Since $\displaystyle E\left( |Y_n|^2\right) = E\left( Y_n^2\right) = \sigma^2$, $|Y_n|$ is uniformly integrable. Thus $E(|Y_n|)\to E(Y)$ and in particular $E(|Y_n|)$ is bounded, as wanted.